# Add notification image in a phonegap project

Tags: android, cordova

I would like to add a set of images to a phonegap project for android, that would be used for displaying notifications. The icons should end up in the res/drawable-xxx directories.

I know how to add icons via the *icon* directive in the config.xml. However, I don't know how to add other images that are not icons or Splash Screens.

Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

I found out a solution. I'm writting it down here just in case someone find it interesting. I solved this problem using an **after_prepare hook**. I placed the source images under myproject/res/android. Then I created a hook script into myproject/hooks/after_prepare. The hook just copy images into the expected platform folders:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Copy resources"

cp res/icons/android/notification-hdpi.png platforms/android/res/drawable-hdpi/notification.png
cp res/icons/android/notification-ldpi.png platforms/android/res/drawable-ldpi/notification.png
...
```

It is simple and works ok